# {file} requires the ionCube PHP Loader ioncube_loader_lin_5.5.so to be installed

Tags: php, vagrant, ioncube

I am trying to run a site locally on vagrant box.  I have all the files downloaded from the clients server and a copy of the database set up locally.  I have changed the db settings to map to my local setup.

When I run the site locally I get the above error.  I have ionCube installed locally (running php v5.5) and in my php.ini file I have the following line included.

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\htdocs\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll"
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: did you restart your webserver?

Comment: also, check the output of phpinfo and double check to make sure it is loaded. clearly it isn't.

Comment: I have restarted apache and done a vagrant provison. I have a phpinfo file showing all the php details, but I'll be honest and say I can't see anywhere on there about ionCube.  Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

Your `zend_extension` line is related to windows machine. Vagrant is probably installed with linux in it, so you need to install a separate copy of ioncube loader inside of it and this copy should be built for linux (and, probably, your specific distribution of linux)